# Enable/Disable a button of currently running activity from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have a custom broadcast receiver which fires up my activity. But i dont want to fire up my activity again,i just want to bring the activity to foreground and enable a button which has hidden before. But i am unable to manipulate the Views of a an activity from a broadcast receiver class.

Comment: Hello @Vajid..Even am struggling with the same thing..Have you found any solution for this question..If Yes kindly share it...

Answer (score 0):

How did you bring the activity to foreground?

If you are using the startActivity method,you can put some information in the intent the method used.When the activity is resumed by the intent,it can fetch the information from it and know which button to be enabled/disabled.

Comment: Hello @tianwei..I've used SERVICE to send location updates to server on a button click, and I've used broadcast receiver to auto start the service when the phone restarts..at the same time i need to disable a button which will start the service..how do I do that..